# Is there a way to code a scollbar into Highcharts in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, highcharts, scrollbar

I've done a lot of googling on this and have come up short. I know that you can use a scrollbar with highcharts using javascript but does anyone know how I can create a scrollbar in C#? The library doesn't seem to have a method for it built in.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am wondering if you could use Highstock library for getting scrollbar in your chart.

Comment: Yes I think so Grzegorz but my employer would have to pay for that so i'm finding a way around.  FYI my workaround atm is adjusting the height of the div based on the number of Y axis categories.